# Voice over programming language

Tags: voice

I am looking for a voice over programming language. Instead of using people for voice over, I want to use a computer, which does voice over for different people. Is this type of thing possible, or is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GamedevSE. Could you be bit more specific about your intentions. What are you goals? Have you tried anything? Are you doing a game, does this question belong here? As of now, even thou it seems to be interesting question, it has no information about what have you tried or your own research on this subject. Edit your question, to contain more details, so this can actually be answered fully. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. There are a bunch of speech synthesisers. And like Philipp said, many OSs provide such APIs.

For example, the **Speech Application Programming Interface** or **SAPI** is an API developed by **Microsoft** to allow the use of both **speech synthesis** and **speech  recognition** within Windows applications.

But keep in mind that these synthesisers **DO NOT PRODUCE REALISTIC SOUNDS**.

This is a good question, and a good idea in case you are trying to enhance interaction. But it would only be used for a robot or an emotionaly dead character, (where you might need an intonation thats not normal, and possibly, difficult for real voice acting).

These might be useful:
1. [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_API),
2. [SAPI docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx),
3. [Using SAPI in C# and VB.NET](http://windowscoding.com/blogs/blake/archive/2006/11/01/How-to-use-Microsofts-Speech-API-in-a-managed-application.aspx),
4. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664239/c-sharp-how-to-use-sapi-to-do-speech-to-text).

Hope this helped =)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a "Text to Speech" API or SDK that you can use with the programming language, framework and/or engine you'll be using for your game. Take a look at http://www.ispeech.org/
They provide APIs and SDKs for both text to speech and voice recognition. I saw that their mobile API is free, so you could use that if you wanted to make a game for Android or iOS. Since you didn't specify the platform you want to develop for, I figured I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Many operating systems (like Windows or MacOS) already have a text-to-speech API included. Search the respective documentations for more information. There are also several 3rd party speech synthesis technologies available as an alternative (some of them [can even sing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocaloid)).

But keep in mind that the quality of todays text-to-speech software is not yet an appropriate replacement for real voice actors. It can create comprehensible voice output, but it can not convey emotions as well as a human actor can.